# Restore SQL Server Database - failed: 38(Reached the end of the file.)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am running the following script:

`RESTORE DATABASE [Name_V2]
FROM  DISK = N'C:\20100920_Name_V2.bak'
WITH
MOVE N'Name_V2' TO N'C:\Program Files\...\Name_V2.mdf',
MOVE N'Name_V2_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\...\Name_V2_log.ldf', 
REPLACE,
STATS=1,
FILE=1,
NORECOVERY
GO`

When it runs, I get to 70 percent processed, and I get the following error:

> Msg 3203, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Read on "C:\20100920_Name_V2.bak"
>   failed: 38(Reached the end of the
>   file.)
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating
>   abnormally.

I'm not sure what the problem is.  Can someone shed some light on it?  When I do a RESTORE VERIFYONLY on it, I get the same 'reached end of the file' error.  When I do a RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM  DISK, it comes back with the results listing the .mdf and .ldf.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It turned out to be corrupted somehow. I received another Full Backup (which was also larger in size from the original), and it restored fine using the SSMS UI. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a corrupted or incomplete backup. See this post on msdn blogs http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldisasterrecovery/thread/b57ae7c2-9f86-48e1-a356-ceb105181bf8

**Summary of thread linked..**

It appears that the backup file itself is corrupt, or the copy was incomplete.

Restore reached the end of the backup file before the database was fully restored.

Comment: The lesson here is: always verify your backups!

Answer (score 3):

This issue is happening because you are using an incomplete backup file.