# How to restore the database.bak file in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a database backup file I need to restore in SQL Server 2008.
I get an error

> Specified cast is not valid. (SqlManagerUI)

Comment: That usually indicates incompatible versions of SQL Server, like the backup is from 2012 but you're attempting to restore into 2008.

Comment: On the error dialog, you can see the incompatible sql versions. Something like `SQL Server 10.50.1600`

Comment: What is the *exact* error message? Press Ctrl+C on the dialog box to copy the entire message text. What are the database versions involved?

Comment: There is at least one duplicate question, eg [SQL Server database restore error: specified cast is not valid. (SqlManagerUI)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604720/sql-server-database-restore-error-specified-cast-is-not-valid-sqlmanagerui). Check the steps described there. The UI often returns invalid messages. Try generating the restore script (click the Script button) and check the actual error message generated when you execute the `RESTORE` statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this first and see if the backup is healthy:

```
DO
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = N'YOURFILE.bak'
```

then we can take it from there

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Msg 3241, Level 16, State 13, Line 1
The media family on device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\mygtl.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally.

Comment: RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = N'YOURFILE.bak'

Comment: I was try this but this was given me like...Msg 3241, Level 16, State 13, Line 1
The media family on device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\mygtl.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally.

Comment: @ManishSolanki: the `MSSQL10_50` in the `.bak` file name seems to indicate a backup from a SQL Server **2008 R2** version - this is **incompatible** with the **2008** version, you **cannot** restore a newer `.bak` file (from SQL Server **2008 R2** - v10.50) onto an older instance of SQL Server, e.g. **2008** (v10.00)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Sql server version of the database from where you have backed up the version of database must be same or upper .Only then you can restore the database backup

Comment: If you read the question, you 'll see that the OP did that and got an error message

Comment: Hello sir, I have one project that was created using c# and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. now I want to add some modules into this project also I have backup file for this database even I can`t restore database in same version of Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.It will give error like Specified cast is not valid. (SqlManagerUI) I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I would appreciate help in this regarding

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604720/sql-server-database-restore-error-specified-cast-is-not-valid-sqlmanagerui) post

Comment: If you are still getting this error and Just try to do it by generating Sql of all the database.